# Revers Engineering CRC 32 in firmware

Tags: reverse-engineering, crc, crc32

i have a p-flash (size is about 700kb) in this flash there is a CRC32. I know where it is, and i know the CRC calculation method (polynomial, initial value, final Xor Value, input and output reflected) the problem is that just a part of these 700kb are used to calculate the crc. And i don't know which part. Is there a way to find out the input data for the calculation?
I have 5 of these 700kb files. The files are all the same except 4 bytes that are different, and the 4 bytes of the crc.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the files onto a PC, that would help. You can xor any two of the files to get a file that is all zeroes except for the 4 different bytes and the 4 bytes of the CRC. The xor of two files will also eliminate any initial value or final xor value, as if initial value = 0 and final xor value = 0. Then check the nearly all zero file to see if the CRC matches what you would expect. If it matches, then you would know that the CRC includes the 4 non-zero bytes and all the zero bytes that follow, but you wouldn't know how far before the 4 non-zero bytes that the CRC includes in its calculation, but this would at least be a start. If it does match, that would reduce the amount of searching for what is included in the CRC calculation.

Assuming the part used for CRC is contiguous, you could do a brute force search using a fast CRC32. On a X86 with SSE2 (xmm) registers, an assembly based CRC32 could calculate a CRC32 for 700,000 bytes in about 0.0002 seconds on an Intel 3770K 3.5ghz a 3rd gen processor (they're faster now), or a bit more than 70 seconds to try lengths from 8 to 700,000 bytes.

I converted the code from this github example to Visual Studio asm, for both reflected and non-reflected CRC, using CRC32 and CRC32C polynomials, and I could upload the code if interested.

https://github.com/intel/isa-l/blob/master/crc/crc16_t10dif_01.asm